# Data-transition effects does not work with tab navigation jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-navbar

I try to bring some effects to my tabs navigation on my jquery-mobile page but it looks like that the data-transitions argument does not work combined with a tabs navigation.

My code looks like this:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a" id="header">
<h1>Mainpage</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs" >
  <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="left">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="lblTab1" href="#location" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn-active" data-icon="search" data-transition="pop">search</a></li>
        <li><a id="lblTab2" href="#product" data-ajax="false" data-icon="location" data-transition="pop">product</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="location" class="ui-body-d ui-content" > content </div>
  <div id="product" class="ui-body-d ui-content" > content2  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

so how is it possible to bring some effects to the navigation bar?

I use jquery-mobile 1.4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page transitions don't work on *tabs* as transition classes are activated when hiding/showing pages. You can create your own transitions, use third party CSS transitions or use jQM default ones.

First, you need to listen to [`tabbeforeactivate`](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-beforeActivate) event. This event omits a `ui` object containing data of previous (`ui.oldPanel`) and next panel (`ui.newPanel`). All you need is to add *animation* classes to `ui-newPanel` and remove them once animation ends by binding *Animation End* **one time** only using `.one()`.

```
$("#tabs").on("tabbeforeactivate", function (e, ui) {
  $(ui.newPanel)
      .addClass("animation")
      .one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
    $(this).removeClass("animation");
  });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/agjAh/)** - Custom animation by [Daneden](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)
>
> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/48kMY/)** - jQM default transitions

Comment: Great solution thanks, but where can I find a list of working animation classes for this? I searched in jqm but couldn't find anything to that.

Comment: @Kingalione for JQM http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/transitions/ for the 3rd party, check the link next to first demo.